# Scalatra and Mongo insertOne error - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.bypassDocumentValidation

Tags: mongodb, scala, scalatra, mongo-scala-driver

After pouring through tutorials and help sites for two days, I cannot seem to find the answer to my question.

I'm new to Scala and Mongo and I'm building an HTTP server using Scalatra (v2.4.1), Scala (v2.11.8) and the mongo-scala-driver (v1.1.1).

The basic Scalatra tutorials for Mongo's `insertOne` function are returning an error:

```
ERROR SalesAppScalatraServlet - Employee insertion failed! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.bypassDocumentValidation(Ljava/lang/Boolean;)Lcom/mongodb/operation/MixedBulkWriteOperation;
at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.executeSingleWriteRequest(MongoCollectionImpl.java:588)
at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:314)
at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:305)
at org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection$$anonfun$insertOne$1.apply(MongoCollection.scala:251)
at org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection$$anonfun$insertOne$1.apply(MongoCollection.scala:251)
at org.mongodb.scala.internal.ObservableHelper$$anon$2.apply(ObservableHelper.scala:42)
at org.mongodb.scala.internal.ObservableHelper$$anon$2.apply(ObservableHelper.scala:40)
at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.requestInitialData(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:39)
at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryRequestInitialData(AbstractSubscription.java:151)
at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.request(AbstractSubscription.java:82)
at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedSubscription.request(ObservableImplicits.scala:382)
at org.mongodb.scala.Observer$class.onSubscribe(Observer.scala:49)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.onSubscribe(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:35)
at org.mongodb.scala.Observer$class.onSubscribe(Observer.scala:85)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.onSubscribe(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:35)
at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.<init>(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:34)
at com.mongodb.async.client.Observables$2.subscribe(Observables.java:76)
at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedObservable.subscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:366)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:35)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet$$anonfun$1.apply(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:31)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet$$anonfun$1.apply(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:31)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.org$scalatra$ScalatraBase$$liftAction(ScalatraBase.scala:285)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$invoke$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:279)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$invoke$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:279)
at org.scalatra.ApiFormats$class.withRouteMultiParams(ApiFormats.scala:189)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.withRouteMultiParams(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.invoke(ScalatraBase.scala:278)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.org$scalatra$json$JsonSupport$$super$invoke(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.json.JsonSupport$$anonfun$invoke$1.apply(JsonSupport.scala:88)
at org.scalatra.json.JsonSupport$$anonfun$invoke$1.apply(JsonSupport.scala:82)
at org.scalatra.ApiFormats$class.withRouteMultiParams(ApiFormats.scala:189)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.withRouteMultiParams(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.json.JsonSupport$class.invoke(JsonSupport.scala:82)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.invoke(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$runRoutes$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:253)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$runRoutes$1$$anonfun$apply$8.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:251)
at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:171)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$runRoutes$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:251)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$runRoutes$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:250)
at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.flatMap(Stream.scala:489)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.runRoutes(ScalatraBase.scala:250)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.runRoutes(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.runActions$1(ScalatraBase.scala:175)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$executeRoutes$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraBase.scala:187)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$executeRoutes$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:187)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$executeRoutes$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:187)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.org$scalatra$ScalatraBase$$cradleHalt(ScalatraBase.scala:205)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.executeRoutes(ScalatraBase.scala:187)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.executeRoutes(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(ScalatraBase.scala:126)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:126)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(ScalatraBase.scala:126)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.scalatra.DynamicScope$class.withResponse(DynamicScope.scala:78)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.withResponse(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.DynamicScope$$anonfun$withRequestResponse$1.apply(DynamicScope.scala:58)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
at org.scalatra.DynamicScope$class.withRequest(DynamicScope.scala:69)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.withRequest(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.DynamicScope$class.withRequestResponse(DynamicScope.scala:57)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.withRequestResponse(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraBase$class.handle(ScalatraBase.scala:125)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.org$scalatra$servlet$ServletBase$$super$handle(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.servlet.ServletBase$class.handle(ServletBase.scala:53)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.org$scalatra$scalate$ScalateSupport$$super$handle(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.scalate.ScalateSupport$class.handle(ScalateSupport.scala:152)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.handle(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet$class.service(ScalatraServlet.scala:60)
at com.syncroness.salesapp.SalesAppScalatraServlet.service(SalesAppScalatraServlet.scala:12)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:751)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:566)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1111)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1045)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:199)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:461)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:534)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Scalatra Servlet is as follows:

```
package com.foo.bar

import com.typesafe.scalalogging.Logger
import java.io.{StringWriter, PrintWriter}
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import org.scalatra._
import org.scalatra.json._
import org.mongodb._
import org.mongodb.scala.{Completed, MongoCollection, MongoDatabase, Document, Observable, Observer}

class SalesAppScalatraServlet(database: MongoDatabase) extends SalesappserverStack with JacksonJsonSupport {

  protected implicit lazy val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats

  val logger = Logger(LoggerFactory.getLogger("SalesAppScalatraServlet"))
  logger.trace("SalesAppScalatraServlet started")

  val employeeCollection: MongoCollection[Document] =     database.getCollection("employee");

  def getStackTraceAsString(t: Throwable) = {
    val sw = new StringWriter
    t.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw))
    sw.toString
  }

  get("/") {
    halt(status = 403, reason = "Forbidden")
  }

  post("/employee") {
    val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> 1, "name" -> "John Smith")

    val observable: Observable[Completed] = employeeCollection.insertOne(doc)
    observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {
      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = logger.info("Employee inserted successfully!")

      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = {
        logger.error("Employee insertion failed! " + getStackTraceAsString(e))
        halt(status = 520, reason = "Insert Employee Error")
      }

      override def onComplete(): Unit = Ok()
    })
  }

  notFound {
    <h2>Page not found</h2>
  }

}
```

My Scalatra Bootstrap file is as follows:

```
import com.foo.bar._
import org.scalatra._
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import org.mongodb.scala.{MongoClient, MongoDatabase}

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext) {
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient()
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("salesAppDB")
    context.mount(new SalesAppScalatraServlet(database), "/*")
  }
}
```

And my build.scala file is as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import org.scalatra.sbt._
import org.scalatra.sbt.PluginKeys._
import com.earldouglas.xwp.JettyPlugin
import com.mojolly.scalate.ScalatePlugin._
import ScalateKeys._

object SalesappserverBuild extends Build {
  val Organization = "com.foo"
  val Name = "SalesAppServer"
  val Version = "1.0.0"
  val ScalaVersion = "2.11.8"
  val ScalatraVersion = "2.4.1"

  lazy val project = Project (
    "salesappserver",
    file("."),
    settings = ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings ++ scalateSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
      resolvers += "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at     "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % ScalaVersion,
        "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "1.1.1",
        "org.fusesource.jansi" % "jansi" % "1.8",
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7" % "runtime",
        "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.4.0",
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.15.v20160210" % "container",
        "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided",
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-json" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.3.0",
        "org.json4s" %% "json4s-mongo" % "3.3.0"
      ),
      scalateTemplateConfig in Compile <<= (sourceDirectory in Compile){ base =>
        Seq(
          TemplateConfig(
            base / "webapp" / "WEB-INF" / "templates",
            Seq.empty,  /* default imports should be added here */
            Seq(
              Binding("context",         "_root_.org.scalatra.scalate.ScalatraRenderContext", importMembers = true, isImplicit = true)
            ),  /* add extra bindings here */
            Some("templates")
          )
        )
      }
    )
  ).enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I've also traced through the scala and java files mentioned in the exception and the method in question - bypassDocumentValidation - does appear to exist.

Comment: Also, my MongoDB version is 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is necro-posting, but still.

Had the same problem just now with morphia+mongo-java-driver. Turns out, the problem is in the driver version. Have it updated to the latest version if you can. For example, this fails:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And this works just fine:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
            <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```